# Query parametrizada com node.js e knex.js

Tags: sql, node.js, express.js

No código abaixo faço uma consulta e trago os contratos que estão concluídos ou não, de acordo com o parâmetro `concluido` (0 ou 1).

Como faço para essa consulta trazer **todos** os contratos quando não for passado o valor do parâmetro `concluido` pela requisição?

```
exports.read = function(req, res) {
    var concluido = parseInt(req.query.concluido);

    knex.select()
    .from('contrato as c')
    .innerJoin('empresa as e', 'e.idempresa', 'c.idempresa')
    .where('c.concluido', concluido)
    .then(function (result) {
        return res.status(200).json(result);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return res.status(400).json(err);
    });
}
```

Atualmente tenho duas funções knex que são chamadas de acordo com as condições, mas como tenho vários parâmetros terei que criar diversas funções, acredito que não seja a maneira correta.

Obs: pode ser algum exemplo em SQL mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é você dividir a string com um condicional:

```
let select = knex.select()
    .from('contrato as c')
    .innerJoin('empresa as e', 'e.idempresa', 'c.idempresa');

if (req.query.concluido) {
    select = select.where('c.concluido', concluido);
}

select
  .then(function (result) {
      return res.status(200).json(result);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(err);
  });
```

Assim só coloca o WHERE caso venha um concluido, e outra opção é usar um truque no SQL:

```
let select = knex.select()
    .from('contrato as c')
    .innerJoin('empresa as e', 'e.idempresa', 'c.idempresa');
    .where('c.concluido', concluido)
    .orWhere(concluido, '');

select
  .then(function (result) {
      return res.status(200).json(result);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(err);
  });
```

o .orWhere ali vai agir quando o concluido vier vazio.